# Error loading KnockoutJS as part of a third party package when host site uses RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

I've developed a JavaScript plugin to be included on our customers' websites.  The plugin I've created depends on some external libraries, which are bundled and delivered to the client as one big package: jQuery 1.8.2 and KnockoutJS v3.0.0.

The plugin plays fine on most sites, but if the host site uses RequireJS, my package fails to load because KnockoutJS automatically detects that RequireJS exists and attempts to use it.  Here is the error that gets thrown:

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module
```

Obviously, I've found an "explanation" of the error message on the RequireJS site.  Unfortunately, I don't understand how to avoid it.  In my local copy of the KnockoutJS library, I've found the offending line:

```
(function(factory) {
    // Support three module loading scenarios
    if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object') {
        // [1] CommonJS/Node.js
        var target = module['exports'] || exports; // module.exports is for Node.js
        factory(target);
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {
        // [2] AMD anonymous module
        define(['exports'], factory);
    } else {
        // [3] No module loader (plain <script> tag) - put directly in global namespace
        factory(window['ko'] = {});
    }
}
```

If I manually edit this file so that condition [2] never executes and only condition [3] every executes, then everything works fine.  Of course, I don't want to do this because it requires me editing an external library, which I'd prefer to keep in pristine condition so I can upgrade it later.

I have a feeling there may be a way to make this work, I just don't understand how RequireJS works.  Obviously, KnockoutJS is TRYING to play nice with RequireJS, but in my case, it's failing.  For me, in this case, even though RequireJS exists, I don't need KnockoutJS to use it.

How can I get these two libraries to work side by side?

EDIT

I have no control over when my library is loaded vs. all other libraries the host site already loads.  In fact, most of the time my plugin will be included, it will be by someone with NO web dev experience using a terrible WYSIWYG platform like WordPress, Webs.com or Weebly so sometimes my script tag might make it to the top of the head element, other times it might be included in the body element somewhere.

Also, to be clear, my library does NOT use RequireJS.  It just so happens that one of our customers that is trying to use my library DOES use RequireJS and when my library gets included, KnockoutJS (bundled with my library, but NOT already on the host site) throws an exception because it thinks it needs to register itself with RequireJS (or at least that's my speculation as to the exception).

While, in principal, I'm not opposed to loading the libraries my code depends on on demand, the truth is that it will create a slow, poor experience for my users as it will take additional request/response cycles to load them.

Comment: Isn't there another problem here in that if the client is already using jQuery and Knockout, your approach will force them to load a 2nd copy? Another approach would be to rethink your packaging structure, detecting and using RequireJS to load those modules when detected.

Comment: How are you loading your plugin? How are the plugin dependencies on jquery and ko specified?

Comment: @explunit -- yes, unfortunately, the current packaging mechanism would cause a second copy to load.  Obviously, this is not preferred, but the testing I've done so far, this hasn't been an issue.  Not optimal, yes?  But acceptable for now.

Comment: @pax162 -- the plugin is simply loaded via one, single script tag that downloads a javascript file will all the dependencies and my custom code all bundled together.  Doing dependency analysis and loading packages on demand from the client would create a really slow experience.  The client page would have to render, then download a first batch of javascript from my servers, then analyze which dependencies needed to be loaded and make another request to get those and then wait for them to load before any of my code could execute.  The result for the client would be a huge initial wait time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the easiest thing to do would probably be to load knockout **before** requirejs. ko will no longer detect that require is present, and will go with option [3]. If you can't do this, the other option is to add your plugin and ko file in a require hierarchy.

So let's say that you plugin looked like this:

```
(function(ko){

//stuff
ko.applyBindings({});

})(ko)
```

You would need to change it to this:

```
require([
    "knockout-3.0.0.js" // this should be the url you use for knockout
    ], function(ko){
       //stuff
       ko.applyBindings({});
})
```

and NOT load the knockout.js file as a separate  tag. Require will handle the loading. The server must still be able to deliver the "knockout-3.0.0.js" url of course. This is how require works. It loads whatever urls you pass as elements in the array parameter of require, and passes what they return as parameters to the function.

If you need to minify/bundle both the plugin file and the ko file into a single file, you can use the reuquirejs minifier/optimizer (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). It will navigate the dependency tree and output only one js file with all modules inside. One quirk here: you need to drop the .js extension for the minifier to work, read more about it the documentation, I just mentioned it to save some headaches.

Also, more documentation on how to use ko with require can be found here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html

EDIT, after op edit:

OK, so in this case you should create a separate scope, in which you can do what you want. You'll need to copy the ko code inside your file, but like this you'll at least get a single file.

So, first create a scope:

```
(function(){

})()
```

Then copy ko code inside:

```
(function(){

//ko code here, should be a single, minified line

})()
```

Then you need to trick ko into using option 3, so do this:

```
(function(){

var define = null; //so define will no longer be a function, don't forget the var
var require = null;
//ko code here, should be a single, minified line

})()
```

Optionally, you might also want to reassign window in the step above, if you don't want ko to be available to the entire page.

And now add your plugin code:

```
(function(){

var define = null; //so define will no longer be a function, don't forget the var
var require = null;
//ko code here, should be a single, minified line

//plugin code here;

})()
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution... Unfortunately, I don't think it will work for me.  I've updated my original question with some clarification, but basically, my plugin does NOT use RequireJS; it just so happens that in this one case, I have a customer trying to use the plugin that DOES use RequireJS for the rest of their site and it's causing a conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I think this solution will work.  It's a little messy, but in my testing so far it seems to solve the issue.